# FTP access on Windows Azure

Tags: ftp, azure, azure-blob-storage

Quick question. I'm currently moving a asp.net MVC web application to the Windows Azure platform. Everything is working out okay apart from one thing.

In the application at the moment, we make use of FTP accounts for each user to import large quantities of files to our database.

I understand FTP on Azure is not as straightforward.

I've googled and found this article: [Ftp on Azure](http://nicoploner.blogspot.com/2010/12/ftp-server-on-windows-azure-from.html)

This seems to be what I need except obviously we'll need to be able to add new users with their own separate FTP account. Does anyone know of an easy workaround for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered altering the system to use blob storage directly?  This seems to me to be a better solution, will scale across multiple instances and is pretty much how it was designed to work.  I upgraded an application in a couple of days from file storage to blob storage and it was pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hi David, I'm going to go with upgrading the application to use BLOB storage. Seems to be the most appropriate solution. Can you recommend any good links/resources that you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider running a (FTP) service that's not IIS based, and you could add users programatically? Also, how are you going to solve data sync issues when the role recycles or when you upgrade it? Make sure to backup to blob on a somewhat regular basis!

Personally, I'd mount a VHD drive (Azure Drive) which is actually hosted on blob storage, and have my FTP server point to that drive. However, make sure you only have one instance of the server (problem #1) unless you don't need higher than 99,9% reliability you can solve this by running a single instance. Step 2 is I'd implement user management in relation to that program.

It's not straightforward, and I'd advise against it though. But I understand that sometimes you have to do this. I would solve it like I described above.